# Find the order of the pole of $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3(z-\pi)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to know as find the order of the poles of function $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3(z-\pi)}$. I found the pole $z = 0$ of second order, but I think that $z=\pi$ is another pole. The question is that I don't know what is the order of this pole. I tried do the limit of $(z-\pi)^n\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3(z-\pi)}$ when $z \to\pi$, but it give $0$. Now when I do $g'(\pi)$, where $g(z)=z^3(z-\pi)$, it give a value different of zero. How do I do it? If someone can help me, I thanks.

Comment: The denominator has a zero of order $1$ at $\pi$.  What about the numerator?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ has a pole at $a$ of order $n\iff$ $f$ can be written as $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^n}$ in some deleted nbd of $a$ w.r.t some, $g$ is holomorphic at $a$ and $g(a)\not=0$$\iff$ $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)^nf(z)\in \Bbb C\backslash \{0\}$.